# Irregular event behavior - firing dependent on subscription to child control's equivalent event

Tags: c#, .net, events, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I encountered this behavior with WinRT's ListView.

`LayoutUpdated` event does fire less often if no event handler is attached to the inner `ScrollViewer`'s `LayoutUpdated` event.

I marked the critical line near the bottom with `// === Critical line ===`.
Removing the leading slashes will lead to `lv_LayoutUpdated` being called more often.

This has implications since the event is fired far too seldom for it to be of any use to me (in the commented-out case)
The problem is, that I cannot set the scroll position before the `ScrollViewer`'s mutation has come to an end. Routing through the `ScrollViewer`'s event seems silly, though.

Is this a bug or is it explainable with bubbling strategies or sth.?

EDIT: BTW, this page is not shown in the app's root frame, but in a frame of a different page if that makes any difference.

EDIT2: I ended up disovering why the firing timing was useless (was doing the data binding async, which screwed with the standard event timings). The behavior persists, though - subscribing to `ScrollViewer`'s event leads to more publishing by the `ListView`'s event. Under what additional circumstances this ends up happening, I do not know. I am using Caliburn.Micro - so maybe their data source wiring does something to the control.
E.g. one issue with CM is, that it swallows the first LayoutUpdated event of the view (if bound via Message:Attach atleast) - although this might only affect the view model.

Anyway, I'll leave this question be for others to disover.

This setup in the code-behind:

```
    public FileListView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var lv = (ListView)FindName("Files");

        lv.Loaded += lv_Loaded;

        lv.LayoutUpdated += lv_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    void lv_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
    {
        var m = (FileListViewModel)DataContext;
        m.Offset = 100;
    }

    void lv_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lv = (ListView)sender;

        var sv = lv.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();

        if (sv == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        //sv.LayoutUpdated += sv_LayoutUpdated; // === Critical line ===
    }

    void sv_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
    {
      // No code here. Just the subscription suffices
    }
```

The XAML:

```
 <Page
    x:Class="Namespace1.FileListView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Poolar.Mobile.PsProject.WinRT.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="61*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="707*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="Files" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="446" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366"
                  Margin="10,10,-10,0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Button x:Name="GoBack" x:Uid="ButtonGoBack" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
  </Page>
```

Comment: I just discovered that there is one more caveat, that the firing behavior of the `ScrollViewer`'s event is dependent on a subscription to the `Items` property's changed event. Any explanation for these kinds of dependencies? I had that registration in my view model.

Comment: Does it happen when you don't use Caliburn.Micro too?